# Azure App Service: Deployment Source missing options [radio vs dropdown]

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, dockerhub, azure-appservice

I set up Azure app service awhile ago and I am recreating an Azure App Service after a large code refactor in a new repo.
However, I am not getting the same options and I see in the original Azure App Service project.

Here is the original Azure App Service project:

[image]

Here is the new Azure App Service project:

[image]

As you can see the original one has radio options with choices for container vs code repo.
And the new one only has a dropdown for code repo options.

It's been awhile, but how did I get one App Azure app instance to have more options for deployments?

Comment: When I Publish the Azure Web App with `Docker Container`, Iam able to see the options with radio and dropdown.  When we Publish the Azure Web App with Code option, the options are different

Comment: What exactly you are looking for ?

Comment: I'm looking for the Source > Container Registry deployment option. 
Did I not make it clear these were the same page on two diff app service instances? 
Why is one giving options for the container and the other only options for code repos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my answer here!
I had to go more carefully and now I see in the form where it asks what type of Instance I want.

Be sure to select  **Docker container**.

[image]